# Real time plotting with plotly

Tags: plotly-python

I have a use case where I wish to plot a dataset as it is gradually filled by an external function in real time. I know the range for the x values ahead of time, so the dataset will initially look something like

```
x   0   1   2   3   4   5
y nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

and as my program progresses the `nans` in the y axis will be filled in - this should trigger the graph to redraw itself. This program will be run from the command line or an ipython/jupyter environment

Is plotly a suitable library for this case, and if so what would it look like? My initial experiments make it seem like plotly is more suited for complex graphs with 'finished' data